# Is it a one-many relationship in Core data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have `category` entity and `subcategory` entity. I need to get subcategory data to that related `categoryId` of category entity.

My `category` entity contains these attributes: "categoryId","categoryName"

`subcategory` contains: "subcategoryId","subcategoryName", "categoryId".

So can any one please guide me how can i put the relationship between this two entity ??

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Rephrase your question please. I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: just i am asking relation between category entity and subcategory entity

Comment: is it one-many relation? or else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Very first you are mixing the concepts of MySQL or SQLite with Core data.** Unlike them Core Data does not have primary-foreign Key concept to relate entities(for easy understanding tables in MySQL). Just create relationship between those entities and you can fetch data their data.

Now about your Entities you have are `category` and `subcategory`. So you have to create relationship between them. If one `category` have many `subcategories` you have to check **To many relationship** option from `Data Model Inspector`..Otherwise One to One relationship would be the one you should go for..Have a look at screenshot how you can make your relationship one to many..

This is a good **tutorial link** for **[one to many relationship](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/09/29/iphone-app-development-tutorial-core-data-part-2-one-to-many-relationship/)**. You can refer if you do not know how to implement.

Also this for tutorial **[simple relationship in Core Data..](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/09/06/iphone-development-core-data-relationships-tutorial-part-1/)**

if you are beginner with Core data you can go with  **[Quick Tutorial Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html)** by Apple and you will get basic idea of Core data.
[image]